# JavaScript get data from Google chrome developers tool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I’m not sure but is there way to access requested data from Chrome’s dev Tools (Network->fetch/xhr->some jsonData)
I‘m looking for a good point to start in JavaScript.
Thanks for your hint.

CU
Alex

I‘ve looked around but I can‘t figure out the best point to start. I hope someone gives me the right hint?

Comment: If something is being displayed in devtools, then it's been made by a request triggered from your page, so you already will have programmatic access to it. Can you be much more specific around the context of your question. I'm guessing that you're attempting to read data of an XHR made in a third-party site, probably via a Chrome extension?

Comment: Yes, a Chrome extension is a way I followed. A request will be done in a third-party site. Always the the same request on the same site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is something requested, then there is already something that is requesting that data.
Anyway you cannot access that data from the dev tools from somewhere else.

What you might want to do or what you can do is to request such data by yourself.
With for example the Fetch API in JavaScript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Maybe that's what you are searching for? Otherwise I would suggest to ask more precise.